# Splitting data in a cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set that looks like this

```
Code   Product
1      A|B
2      A|B|C
3      A|B|C|D|E
```

When I split the column `Product` using `colsplit` function, duplication occurs. The output of `colsplit` function looks like this:

```
Code  Product.1   Product.2  Product.3  Product.4  Product.5
1     A           B          A          B          A
2     A           B          C          A          B
3     A           B          C          D          E
```

This happens because one of the cells had five elements. Is there any way to avoid this duplication?

Thanks and regards
Jayaram

Comment: Do you want the output to be in wide or long format? The first line in wide would be `A,B,NA,NA,NA` and in long format it would be represented by the two lines `1,1,A` and `1,2,B`.

Comment: wide format would be appropriate because some more transformations need to be done. It would be very helpful if you could give me the code and functions required

Comment: one more requirement is there a code to avoid the NA in the unwanted cells

Comment: thanks a lot for all the help the code is working fine is there a way to remove NA in the cells

Comment: No. All rows of a `data.frame` must have the same number of columns, so `NA` is used whenever there is no value put in a cell. I would suggest using a list instead, try `strsplit(x$Product, "\\|")`.

Comment: @ Backlin and Ananda Mahto what would be the appropriate concat.split function if i want the output in the long format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update (21 Oct 2013)

The concepts below have been rolled into a family of functions called `concat.split.*` in my "splitstackshape" package. Here is a very straightforward solution using `concat.split.multiple`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(temp, "Product", "|", "long")
#    Code time Product
# 1     1    1       A
# 2     2    1       A
# 3     3    1       A
# 4     1    2       B
# 5     2    2       B
# 6     3    2       B
# 7     1    3    <NA>
# 8     2    3       C
# 9     3    3       C
# 10    1    4    <NA>
# 11    2    4    <NA>
# 12    3    4       D
# 13    1    5    <NA>
# 14    2    5    <NA>
# 15    3    5       E
```

Remove the `"long"` argument if you want the wide format, but your comments indicated that ultimately you wanted a long format for your output.

---

#### Original answer (17 Dec 2012)

You can do this with `strsplit` and `sapply` as follows:

```
# Your data
temp <- structure(list(Code = 1:3, Product = c("A|B", "A|B|C", "A|B|C|D|E"
)), .Names = c("Code", "Product"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

temp1 <- strsplit(temp$Product, "\\|") # Split the product cell
temp1 <- data.frame(Code = temp$Code, 
                    t(sapply(temp1, 
                           function(x) { 
                               temp <- matrix(NA, 
                                              nrow = max(sapply(temp1, length)));
                               temp[1:length(x)] <- x; temp})))
temp1
#   Code X1 X2   X3   X4   X5
# 1    1  A  B <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2    2  A  B    C <NA> <NA>
# 3    3  A  B    C    D    E
```

---

Or... use `rbind.fill` from the "plyr" package, after making each of your rows into a single column `data.frame`:

```
temp1 <- strsplit(temp$Product, "\\|")
library(plyr)
data.frame(Code = temp$Code, 
           rbind.fill(lapply(temp1, function(x) data.frame(t(x)))))
#   Code X1 X2   X3   X4   X5
# 1    1  A  B <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2    2  A  B    C <NA> <NA>
# 3    3  A  B    C    D    E
```

---

Or... inspired by @DWin's great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924245/1270695), re-read the second column as a `data.frame` in itself.

```
newcols <- max(sapply(strsplit(temp$Product, "\\|"), length))
temp2 <- data.frame(Code = temp$Code,
                    read.table(text = as.character(temp$Product), 
                               sep="|", fill=TRUE, 
                               col.names=paste("Product", seq(newcols))))
temp2
#   Code Product.1 Product.2 Product.3 Product.4 Product.5
# 1    1         A         B                              
# 2    2         A         B         C                    
# 3    3         A         B         C         D         E
```

Comment: @ ananda mahto the output is in the wide format. can the function be changed so that the output is in long format

Comment: @jayaram8569, you can do this in an additional step. Assuming you used the `concat.split` function and stored the output as `temp1`, you can try: `reshape(temp1, direction = "long", idvar="Code", varying=2:ncol(temp1), sep="_")`.