# split values and then operate with them using R

Tags: r

I've got a data.frame with 3 columns. The third column has either numbers or character type "1:5", "30:20", "1:10", etc. I'm trying to split the values which have those characters into two and then divide between them but I'm stuck with this:

```
    datos[,3]=gsub(":", " ", datos[,3])
    if (datos[,1]==TRUE)
    {
    s=datos[,3]
    chr.pos <- which(unlist(strsplit(s,NULL)) == " ") 
    chr.count <- length(chr.pos)
    one=as.numeric(substr(s,1,chr.pos-1))
    two=as.numeric(substr(s,chr.pos+1,nchar(as.character(s))))
    datos[,3]=round(two/one,5)
    }
```

Comment: When you say `data.table`, do you mean [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) or just a `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks I mean that I used the instruction read.csv but to be honest I don't know very well the difference between the two.

Comment: If you used read.csv, then you have a 'dataframe'. Please study your introductory material more carefully.

Comment: Thanks you're right. As the third column contains numerical data "mixed" with these strings with columns it is difficult for me to find the right command that works for both.

Comment: Your third column cannot have "mixed" data.  columns of data.frames can only be of one type.  however, if you have some rows that are the string one (`"1"`) and others that are the string `"1:5"`, how do you want those cases handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Note: Added 'col.names' to suppress default handling of rownames.

```
x=c("1", "2", "3", "2:3","4","5","3:2")
 datos <- data.frame(1:7, 1:7, x=x)
newframe <- cbind( datos[1:2], 
                 read.table(text= as.character(datos[[3]]), sep=":",
                            fill=TRUE, colClasses="numeric", 
                           col.names=c("V3", "V4")
                           )
                  )

> newframe
  X1.7 X1.7.1 V3 V4
1    1      1  1 NA
2    2      2  2 NA
3    3      3  3 NA
4    4      4  2  3
5    5      5  4 NA
6    6      6  5 NA
7    7      7  3  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I get the following error: Error in textConnection(text) argument not valid. I believe it might be because of both data types in the same column.

Comment: Fixed. Was a factor variable due to the default R setting for stringsAsFactors.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I find is that in your example the x vector always has a colon and my x vector is similar to this x=c(1, 2, 3, "2:3",4,5,"3:2"). I have changed the data.frame so I have in the first column TRUE if column 3 has a colon and FALSE if not. Is there a way that If column 1 is TRUE then split the string, convert both sides of the splitted string to numeric and divide them so I have finally just one number? I'm trying a loop as well but doesn't work.

Comment: Your description is not clear to me. Try posting dput() on your example and post in the answer body rather than the comments.

Comment: Great solution. I've added it as [one of several options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13912721/1270695) to a very similar question. How does one go about merging questions?

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm! thanks very much to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you can be sure that there are always two numbers separated by a colon, `:` you can do the following:

```
x <- c('1:5', '30:20', '1:10')
strsplit(x, ':')

lapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(v) as.integer(v[1])/as.integer(v[2]))
```

Then assign that back to where you wanted it.  if its a data.frame:

```
datos[,3] <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(v) as.integer(v[1])/as.integer(v[2]))
)
```

---

walking through that stuff:

`strsplit` returns a list of vectors containing the things on either side of the split character you pass (I used `:`).  Take a look at what it does:

```
str(strsplit(x, ':'))

List of 3
 $ : chr [1:2] "1" "5"
 $ : chr [1:2] "30" "20"
 $ : chr [1:2] "1" "10"
```

`lapply` acts on a list applying the function you specify to each element of the list.  I defined a function that divides the first value of `v` by the second.  However, I needed coerce them to numbers since they come out of the `strsplit` as character strings.

Finally, `lapply` also returns a list.  If you assign this directly to a column of your `data.frame` you'll be in for an unpleasant surprise.  Instead, use `unlist` to change the list to a vector and assign that to your `data.frame` column.

Also, as mnel alluded to in the comment, `data.table` is a package for R that has some wonderful functionality but much different syntax from the base R data structure `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and explanations. I'm getting an error using strsplit(x, ":"). I think it is because the file that I read contains other data type in the same column (without any colon). The error is argument type non-character.

Comment: you can use `str` to look at your data.  However, that error is telling you the column you are sending to `strsplit` is not a character type (its probably numeric!).

Comment: @user1228124 adding the output of `str(datos)` and `dput(head(datos))` to your question will help a bunch with figuring out whats going on.

Comment: This gives me much more information. The third variable/column is $ V3: Factor.

Comment: factors are wonderful but will give you surprising results when you don't know they're there.  look at `?factor` for more info on converting back to character or numeric from a factor.